# How to move object in its local transform orientation in Animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

How can I move an object in its local transform orientation in animation nodes?

There is a way using some math with rotation of the object as an input,but I want to know if there is an easier way to do it in animation nodes.

Comment: Can you closer specify what you would like to achieve?

Comment: I want to move an object in it's local transform orientation,means if the object is rotated 45 degree in the x axis and i want to move it in it's local transform orientation,it will move along the axis of the new rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can make use of Matrix nodes:

[image]

Note that the order to combine Translation and Rotation matrix data is the key here.